# Starting an INDIVIDUAL instance of a subclass from asynchat

Tags: python, asyncore

So the situation I have is that I have loaded more than one class that I've made that subclasses from `asynchat`, but I only want one of them to run. Of course, this doesn't work out when I call `asyncore.loop()` as they all begin. Is there any way to make only one of them begin running?

**edit:** I think it has something to do with the `map` parameter that can be passed to `asyncore.loop` but I can't get it working.

**edit2:** I got it. Basically I did the following:

```
asyncore.loop(map=my_instance._map)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For all who were curious, I figured it out. If you pass your instance's `_map` to `loop()` it seems to only start the single instance.

Example:

```
my_asyncore_obj = SomeAsyncoreObj()
asyncore.loop(map=my_asyncore_obj._map)
```